# Phaser Move camera mouse position bug

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

So, I have a simple circle sprite, that's following the mouse, Like this:

```js
this.input.on('pointermove', function (pointer) {
   this.circle.setPosition(pointer.x, pointer.y);
}, this);
```

However, I also have camera movement by arrow key,

```js
//  Camera controls
    const cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();

    const controlConfig = {
      camera: this.cameras.main,
      left: cursors.left,
      right: cursors.right,
      up: cursors.up,
      down: cursors.down,
      acceleration: 0.06,
      drag: 0.0005,
      maxSpeed: 1.0,
    };

    this.controls = new Phaser.Cameras.Controls.SmoothedKeyControl(
      controlConfig
    );
```

When I move the camera around without moving the mouse, the circle sprite gets off the mouse, and still moves like the mouse does, but from where it is, not where the mouse is. How do I fix this?

Edit: this happens with anything dragged by the mouse, How do I fix this any mouse dragged object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to change pointer.x to pointer.worldX, and pointer.y to pointer.worldY